# Use Apple Shortcut to create new Notion page without internet access?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, internet, shortcuts-app

I wrote a Shortcut that allows me to create a new Notion page. It sends an authenticated API request to https://api.notion.com/. While this works, it has the disadvantage that it requires internet access. By contrast, if I create a page using the Notion iOS app itself, the creation will succeed even without internet - the app will take care of syncing when I have internet later.

Is there any way that I can get my shortcut to cause the app itself to create the page, allowing it to work even when offline?

Answer (score 0):

While I believe the short answer is no — the Notion app doesn’t currently offer any hooks into it from Shortcuts (aside from opening some suggested pages) — there may be another way to accomplish what you want, although imperfectly.

You could use an Automation in Shortcuts triggered by opening the Notion app that checks if you have internet access, and if so would then send your notion api request. This would involve adding logic to your current shortcut that stores the api request somewhere — like Files or in a dictionary app like DataJar — in the event of not having internet access, otherwise it sends the api request per usual. And then more logic in that shortcut that when it’s triggered by the Automation, it pulls each api request from wherever they get stored and sends them as usual to the Notion api. Other possible Automation triggers to use would be time of day — you could theoretically manually set an automation to run every minute; perhaps once an hour would be sufficient for your needs — or joining a wi-fi network/s, though the latter prompts you to run the shortcut rather than doing so automatically.